# Joomla 2.5: display site title in specific menu

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm maintaining an older site that's build in joomla 2.5
http://arwos.dk/

The site features an intranet with a calendar that keeps track on peoples birthdays. Every person has an article, and all of these articles is displayed in a menu called birthdays.

The site features numerous menus, and when the page was build, it was decided that the page title should be hidden unless manually turned on. The birthdays, however, is loaded in with XML and there is alot of them, so it's not realistic to turn on the page title one by one.

Is there a way i can turn on the page title for JUST the birthdays menu items?

Sorry if this has been asked about before, i couldn't seem to find an answer through the search.

Answer (score 0):

If the menu type of birthdays menu is Category list/blog, then you should navigate to the **Page display** tab and then enter your desired page title under **Page Heading**. I hope that helps.